# Weird flow with error handling with VBA Input Box?

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I am trying to understand why the following code is not giving me the expected behaviour.

I would like to ask the user for a decimal number (double). I have an error handler below but the way this program behaves, it will still throw errors when I input either a word or number. It will catch the error when I don't put anything though (empty input).

**When I remove the if condition, it will work as expected but I do not know how to catch empty user inputs.**

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub MainTask()

Dim userInput As Double

TryAgain:
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    userInput = InputBox("What is the amount purchased you would like to search for? ($)")
    If Len(userInput) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox "You have entered a valid value!"
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Please enter a valid value."
GoTo TryAgain

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry about that. It is `vba`

Comment: When you `GoTo TryAgain` within the error handler you are still within the error handler for the current error so subsequent errors are unhandled.  Replacing `GoTo TryAgain` with `Resume` would fix this but its not a very good way of doing things, for example the user will get an error on the cancel button, you should use a string and test it against `""` and `IsNumeric()`

Comment: InputBox returns a String. You cannot assign the return value to a Double. If it's not a number it will throw an error.

Comment: For your specific case, use `userInput = application.InputBox("What is the amount purchased you would like to search for? ($)", type:=1)`. For general case of handling inputs, refer to [Scott Craner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268448/11683).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not like error handling as it will cover other problems:

```
Sub MainTask()

Dim userInput As Variant
Dim output As Double

Do
    userInput = InputBox("What is the amount purchased you would like to search for? ($)")
    If Len(userInput) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(userInput) Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid value."        
Loop Until IsNumeric(userInput)

output = userInput
MsgBox "You have entered a valid value! " & output   

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is great!

Comment: Best error handling == no error handling. +1 for avoiding error conditions.

Comment: @Mat'sMug there are times, when using `Application.WorkSheetFunction.Match()` I like to use `On Error Resume Next` and immediately turn it back on then test whether the error happened, to see if the match found anything or not.

Comment: That one is easily avoided with the late-bound `Application.Match` version though, but yeah, no harm done with OERN over *one* statement ;-)

Comment: You know, You and I had this conversation a few months back, where you stated it would be better to do it this way instead of late bound, that it would probably be quicker? @Mat'sMug

Comment: Indeed, indeed! Late-bound penalty cannot be overstated - especially in loops. I guess, as with many things, #ItDepends =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug how is `application.match` late bound?

Comment: @Rory because it's a member of an extended COM interface that VBA gets you no compile-time validation for, so it must resolve at run-time.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Validation of what exactly?

Comment: @Rory the `Excel.Application` COM interface is marked as *extensible*. This means `Application.IDontExist` will happily compile, and it's at run-time that VBA will raise error 438 when it can't find that `IDontExist` member on the run-time type; when a member call is resolved at run-time, it's a late-bound call that the compiler cannot determine as valid: hence *validation* (for lack of a better word?) of late-bound calls is deferred to run-time. Early-bound calls are validated at compile-time, e.g. `Application.WorksheetFunction.IDontExist` won't compile.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm confused as to how that would be possible. If `Application.blah` will compile, so should `Application.WorksheetFunction.blah` by the same logic - and indeed it does. So effectively any application method/property should be late bound by implication, but it isn't. How come?

Comment: Non-extensible interfaces don't allow this... whether a given interface is extensible or not isn't exactly easily discoverable in VBA, but if you get IntelliSense for a member you're looking at an early-bound call. I have to admit I hadn't realized WorksheetFunction was (apparently) also an extensible interface.

Comment: @Rory FWIW - The `Application.FunctionName` approach is late-bound and a throw-back to Excel 95. The chief differences being: Late-bound performance, no Intellisense, and silent errors. And while `Application.WorksheetFunction` would seem to be extensible, it does have early bound references to the worksheet functions, so you get early-bound performance, you get Intellisense, and you get compilation of any early-bound members that are misused or are missing arguments. For example, you can't use `x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum` without getting a *Compile Error - Argument not optional*.

Comment: Whereas, `x = Application.Sum` will happily compile